# using python to pull href tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, href

tyring to pull the href links for the products on this webpage. The code pulls all of the href's except the products that are listed on the page.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.neb.com/search#t=_483FEC15-900D-4CF1-B514-1B921DD055BA&sort=%40ftitle51880%20ascending"

response = requests.get(url)

data = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

tags = soup.find_all('a')

for tag in tags:
    print(tag.get('href'))
```

Comment: A quick look at the network inspector tells me that there are 13323 records in that recordset. Also the results are formatted on the client-side from a json payload so I would imagine you'll have much better luck with the structured format. Either way, you'll have to deal with the pagination.

Answer (score 1):

The products are loaded through rest API dynamically, the URL is this:
https://international.neb.com/coveo/rest/v2/?sitecoreItemUri=sitecore%3A%2F%2Fweb%2F%7BA1D9D237-B272-4C5E-A23F-EC954EB71A26%7D%3Flang%3Den%26ver%3D1&siteName=nebinternational

Loading this response will get you the URLs.

Next time, check your network inspector if any part of web page isn't loading dynamically (or use selenium).

Answer (score 0):

Try to verify if the product href's is in the received response. I'm telling you to do this because if the part of the products is being dynamically generated by ajax, for example, a simple get on the main page will not bring them.

Print the response and verifiy if the products are being received in the html

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

for numb in ('1', '100'):
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.neb.com/search#first=" + numb + "&t=_483FEC15-900D-4CF1-B514-1B921DD055BA&sort=%40ftitle51880%20ascending")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, from_encoding=resp.info().get_param('charset'))

    for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        print(link['href'])
```